# New to working out, is this good?

Tags: strength, muscle-gain, martial-arts

I want to do martial arts but I'm very physically weak, I struggle to do 15 push ups in one go. I've got a very slim build and a bony body (this helps in fights because I have a harder than normal skeleton). My waist size is roughly 28-30 inches in circumference. Weight is 50kg. I don't know other info you may need but ask if you do.

I'm currently starting with a small warm up, jogging for about 1 minute around the garden, stretching for another and then I start working my muscles. I do 10 push ups and then 20 squats and repeat that 5 times, take a 2-3 minute break and then do it again. after that I throw punches with my weight and muscle behind each one 150 times and go straight to... I have no idea what there called, I think crunches? hands behind my head lying down and lift myself with my stomach until elbows touch my knees, I do this thirty times, 1 minute break and then another 30. I know what to eat but I want confirmation if this is good or not, self made workout and I have no weights so I'm doing what I can.

I also want to improve my reaction time, mine can take nearly half a second at its worst and 250ms at its best and I heard there are exercises that can improve that, I play games a lot of my day because I have nothing else to do. Anything else I should do?

Comment: Weight without age/height isnt very meaningfull.

Comment: eat more.. and increase protein if you wish to build muscle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks good to me! Congrats on taking control of your own fitness! My advice:
1) Log your activities each time you do them.
2) Every so often (eg, weekly, biweekly, etc), gradually increase the difficulty of your overall workout. You can increase the difficulty by adding sets/reps, adding exercises, decreasing rest, etc. However, do not make huge jumps that are not sustainable.

The goal is gradually increase your work capacity over time. Also, be realistic with your performance levels: You will encounter personal setbacks, illnesses, etc, so you will have occasional regressions. Don't let these setbacks cause you to give up. Just dust yourself off, and try to stay active...then resume your lifelong journey towards gradual improvement over time.

Comment: This is a great answer! I just wanna add that if you're looking for a real smooth app to log your workouts check out https://ewolo.fitness !

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get stronger, put on muscle and be overall healthier, depending on your age I would recommend resistance training.  Find a good weight routine that suites your schedule.  You can go to bodybuilding.com or just get the bodyspace app and there are tons of routines that break down every exercise step by step and let you log your activities.

Just be sure to ease into it.  Never bite off more than you can chew and you NEED to establish a baseline before you dive into heavy weight.  Along with a good weight routine, a healthy and proper diet, good sleep and time, you will get stronger.